# How to merge three TCP streams in realtime

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have three bits of networked realtime data logging equipment that output lines of ASCII text via TCP sockets.  They essentially just broadcast the data that they are logging - there are no requests for data from other machines on the network.  Each piece of equipment is at a different location on my network and each has a unique IP address.

I'd like to combine these three streams into one so that I can log it to a file for replay or forward it onto another device to view in realtime.

At the moment I have a PHP script looping over each IP/port combination listening for up to 64Kb of data.  As soon as the data is received or it gets an EOL then it forwards that on to another which that listens to the combined stream.

This works reasonably well but one of the data loggers outputs far more data than the others and tends to swamp the other machines so I'm pretty sure that I'm missing data.  Presumably because it's not listening in parallel.

I've also tried three separate PHP processes writing to a shared file in memory (on /dev/shm) which is read and written out by a fourth process.  Using file locking this seems to work but introduces a delay of a few seconds which I'd rather avoid.

I did find a PHP library that allows true multithreading using Pthreads called (I think) Amp but I'm still not sure how to combine the output.  A file in RAM doesn't seem quick enough.

I've had a good look around on Google and can't see an obvious solution.  There certainly doesn't seem to be a way to do this on Linux using command line tools that I've found unless I've missed something obvious.

I'm not too familiar with other languages but are there other languages that might be better suited to this problem ?

Based on the suggested solution below I've got the following code almost working however I get an error 'socket_read(): unable to read from socket [107]: Transport endpoint is not connected'.  This is odd as I've set the socket to accept connections and made it non-blocking.  What am I doing wrong ?:

```
// Script to mix inputs from multiple sockets

// Run forever
set_time_limit (0);

// Define address and ports that we will listen on
$localAddress=''; 

// Define inbound ports
$inPort1=36000;
$inPort2=36001;

// Create sockets for inbound data
$inSocket1=createSocket($localAddress, $inPort1);
$inSocket2=createSocket($localAddress, $inPort2);

// Define buffer of data to read and write
$buffer="";

// Repeat forever
while (true) {
    // Build array streams to monitor
    $readSockets=array($inSocket1, $inSocket2);
    $writeSockets=NULL;
    $exceptions=NULL;
    $t=NULL;

    // Count number of stream that have been modified
    $modifiedCount=socket_select($readSockets, $writeSockets, $exceptions, $t);

    if ($modifiedCount>0) {

        // Process inbound arrays first
        foreach ($readSockets as $socket) {
            // Get up to 64 Kb from this socket
            $buffer.=socket_read($socket, 65536, PHP_BINARY_READ);
        }

        // Process outbound socket array
        foreach ($writeSockets as $socket) {
            // Get up to 64 Kb from this socket and add it to any other data     that we need to write out
            //socket_write($socket, $buffer, strlen($buffer));
            echo $buffer;
        }

        // Reset buffer
        $buffer="";
    } else {
        echo ("Nothing to read\r\n");
    }

}

function createSocket($address, $port) {
    // Function to create and listen on a socket

    // Create socket
    $socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    echo ("SOCKET_CREATE: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\r\n");

    // Allow the socket to be reused otherwise we'll get errors
    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
    echo ("SOCKET_OPTION: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\r\n");

    // Bind it to the address and port that we will listen on
    $bind=socket_bind($socket, $address, $port);
    echo ("SOCKET_BIND: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . " $address:$port\r\n");

    // Tell socket to listen for connections
    socket_listen($socket);
    echo ("SOCKET_LISTEN: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\r\n");

    // Make this socket non-blocking
    socket_set_nonblock($socket);

    // Accept inbound connections on this socket
    socket_accept($socket);

    return $socket;
}
```

Comment: For best performance, the normal go-to languages are native, i.e. C and C++. C++ gives you essentially everything C does, and better abstractions. Also, it is fun to program near the metal. Learn C++11/14/17 with smart pointers, auto, STL containers and lambdas, it is not as difficult as some would have you believe.

Comment: Unfortunately timescales don't permit me the time to learn another language although C++ is on the list to learn at some point as I'm aware of PHP's limitations especially on tasks such as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessary need to switch languages, it just sounds like you're not familiar with the concept of IO multiplexing. Check out some documentation for the PHP `select` call [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php)

The concept of listening to multiple data inputs and not knowing which one some data will come from next is a common one and has standard solutions. There are variations on exactly how its implemented but the basic idea is the same: you tell the system that you're interested in receiving data from multiple source simultaneously (TCP sockets in your case), and run a loop waiting for this data. On every iteration of the loop the system the system tells you which source is ready for reading. In your case that means you can piecemeal-read from all 3 of your sources without waiting for an individual one to reach 64KB before moving on to the next.

This can be done in lots of languages, including PHP.

**UPDATE:** Looking at the code you posted in your update, the issue that remains is that you're trying to read from the wrong thing, namely from the listening socket rather than the connection socket. You are ignoring the return value of `socket_accept` in your `createSocket` function which is wrong.

Remove these lines from `createSocket`:

```
// Accept inbound connections on this socket
socket_accept($socket);
```

Change your global socket creation code to:

```
// Create sockets for inbound data
$listenSocket1=createSocket($localAddress, $inPort1);
$listenSocket2=createSocket($localAddress, $inPort2);
$inSocket1=socket_accept($listenSocket1);
$inSocket2=socket_accept($listenSocket2);
```

Then your code should work.

Explanation: when you create a socket for binding and listening, its sole function then becomes to accept incoming connections and it cannot be read from or written to. When you accept a connection a new socket is created, and this is the socket that represents the connection and can be read/written. The listening socket in the meantime continues listening and can potentially accept other connections (this is why a single server running on one http port can accept multiple client connections).

Comment: Thanks for that.  I wasn't aware of that command.  I'm slowly cutting my teeth on socket programming !  I'll give your suggestion a go and will report back.

Comment: I've got something almost working and I've added the code to the original post.  If you get a moment, could you suggest why I'm getting the error that I am.

Comment: I've updated my answer, should solve your problem I hope